# Refer to Sheets by Index Number

Tags: excel, vba

I have several sheets in my workbook.

When I type sheet5.Name it returns the name of the sheet, lets say "BOOK".

When I type `sheets("BOOK").Index` it returns another number. If number 5 is the number of this sheet why doesn't it return 5?

I wrote a function to get sheetnumber, I have names of sheets and I want to get their numbers. When I check I see that the numbers which it returns are not as I expect.

```vb
Function shtNum(ByVal shtName As String) As Integer
    ' declerations
    Dim Wks As Worksheet
    
    ' body
    For Each Wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Wks.Name = shtName Then
            shtNum = Wks.Index
        End If
    Next
    
End Function
```

How can I get sheet number when I have name of the sheet?

Comment: `sheet5` is the code name, the index is the order they appear at the bottom.

Comment: There's no guarantee that a sheet with the codename `sheet5` is in the 5th position. But `Worksheet.Index` as you're using it is appropriate here.

Comment: The advantage of using the sheet's codename is that is *doesn't* change if the tab is moved or the tab name is changed.

Comment: If it's really an issue that you couldn't solve by calling directly the sheet name, you could write a function that stores the index according to the sheet by using [dicitonaries](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/) and then retrieve it as needed.

Comment: Thanks from everyone, You survived me by your helps.